# Your iOS Development certificate has been revoked?

Tags: ios

You have revoked your certificate, so it is no longer valid.

Certificate: iOS Development

Team Name:

Any provisioning profiles that include this certificate are no longer valid and must be regenerated for future use.

Best regards,

Apple Developer Program Support

I don't know what it means and how should I do?

Comment: Make a new development certificate.

Comment: I have had the same problem and found this answer all I needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689116/certificate-has-either-expired-or-has-been-revoked.

Answer (score 3):

It probably means you, or someone else with access to the same development account had Xcode auto-generate a new development certificate for it to use. The first step there is to revoke the old one.

These messages look much scarier than they actually are. You may have to go into the member center and tell your provisioning profiles to use that new certificate now, then redownload them.

If you were the one who initiated the certificate creation in Xcode, then you should be all set. If you were not, and you need to use the same account for development, then have whomever clicked the button export the certificate for you, then you shouldn't have a problem building to a device after installing it on your computer.

If you and everybody else on the account don't have a current development certificate, then just make a new one.